# How do I change the background color of a matplotlib inline plot in LightTable?

Tags: python, matplotlib, lighttable

How do I change the background color of the sides of a matplotlib inline plot in LightTable?  In the image below, it's a little difficult to see the axis labels.  I'm fine with either a python-based solution (i.e. modification of the python code shown), or a LightTable-based solution (i.e. a change in one of the settings files, but I'm not sure which one--e.g. is it user.behaviors?).

[image: Matplotlib inline plot in Light Table]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create a figure first, you can set the background colour using `patch.set_facecolor`:

```
fig=plt.figure()
fig.patch.set_facecolor('white')
```

Not sure if that works in LightTable (never used it before), but that does work in an ipython session so hopefully its portable to LightTable